# How to call handler function from a child of a child component (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm wondering what is the best way of doing this.

I have 3 components, App, String and Note. Before I was creating Note elements in App like this:

```
<Note
          state={this.state.btnStates[i]}
          onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)}
        />
```

and it was working like charm (handleClick is of course in the most parent component - App)

but now I want to transfer note creation to the String component, I thought that would be easy but what I thought to work just doesn't. I'm doing it like this:
in App component i render String:

```
          <String
            btnStates={this.state.btnStates}
            onClick={(i) => this.handleClick(i)}
          ></String>
```

in String component:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < stringLength; i++) {
      notes.push(
        <Note
          key={i}
          onClick={keyFromNoteCall => this.props.onClick(keyFromNoteCall)}
          state={this.props.btnStates[i]}
        ></Note>
      );
    }
```

and in Note component:

```
      <input
        type="button"
        className={this.getClassName(this.props.state)}
        onClick={() => this.props.onClick(this.props.key)}
        value={this.props.value}
        disabled={this.isDisabled()}
      />
```

What is the React way of doing such things? I need the logic to be handled in the App, but I would like move the rendering of Notes in a loop to another component.

*UPDATE: it turned out the problem was "key" property as it can't be accessed with `{this.props.key}` I created another property "id" for that purpose and it works. I have another problem now, that even after binding in App constructor, `this` logged in handleClick function doesn't show App component but rather the Note itself :/

Answer (score 1):

Without using a state handler like Context or Redux, the React way of doing it is passing the function as props.

App.js

```
<String
    btnStates={this.state.btnStates}
    handleClick={this.handleClick}
/>
```

String component

```
for (var i = 0; i < stringLength; i++) {
      notes.push(
        <Note
          key={i}
          handleClick={this.props.handleClick}
          state={this.props.btnStates[i]}
        ></Note>
      );
    }
```

Note component

```
<input
    type="button"
    className={this.getClassName(this.props.state)}
    onClick={() => this.props.handleClick(this.props.key)}
    value={this.props.value}
    disabled={this.isDisabled()}
  />
```

Also I recommend you that in your String component you do a .map() instead of a for loop.

```
notes.map(note => 
    <Note key={note.id} 
    handleClick={this.props.handleClick}
    state={note.btnStates}
)
```

This way you would have to refactor to have IDs on your notes but you should do it because using indexes as keys can cause problems.

Comment: somehow it doesn't work for me, would you mind sharing an example of full basic code where this actually works?

Comment: *I've updated the main post, with the progress I've been able to make on this.

Comment: Can you share your repository?

Comment: https://github.com/tkozuch/react-test/blob/master/test-multi-component.jsx
this is an example of how I tried to recreate this issue. So this is how I'm creating it basically in normal example, and I have the same issue here.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you should change onClick in App to this and that should do it.

```js
<String
    btnStates={this.state.btnStates}
    onClick={this.handleClick}
/>
```